# Why do we have dbo user as owner for dbo schema?

Tags: sql-server

I understand that `dbo` is a default schema for every object in database owned by `dbo` user but we can't login with `dbo` user and the account we specify during setup gets rights automatically.

Why do we have a `dbo` user for `dbo` schema if we can't login with it. We could have had the setup account with full previleges on all schemas.

What's the significance of it?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to use `dbo` schema till in DB we don't have another objects with same name in anothers schemas. 
But if you build queries without specifying this, then the speed of query execution will slow down. Since the query optimizer will scan other schemes. You can assume that this is just a default namespace

Comment: Hello Igor..thanks for the reply. I understand the two part naming concept and I know dbo schema too. Why do we have "dbo" user is my question. Any DB_Owner or sysadmin could have been the owner of different schemas ( like dbo schema or sales schema ...etc)